# Submitting a form to a php script

Tags: php, html, forms, xss

I have a simple form which asks for some data which is then submitted and the data is sent to me via email.

I have written the php script and all works fine, but I am working through a tutorial as I am a total newbie to php.

In this tutorial it mentions some security issues when submitting a form which can allow a hacker to inject some js into your code.

The article suggests using

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

which as I understand it will prevent the injection of js by converting any characters not understood in html.

When I put this code in my form though I get an error 
saying `unexpected character after attribute value.`

The whole form in html looks like this,

```
<div class="container">

    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="name"> First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="firstname" class="form-control" required="true">
        </div>
        <div>
      <label for="name"> Last Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div>
      <label for="mail"> E-mail:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="true">
  </div>
  <div>
      <label for="number"> Phone:</label>
      <input type="number" name="phone" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div>
      <label for="msg"> Message:</label>
      <textarea type="text" name="message" class="form-control" required="true" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
      <input type="checkbox" name="consent">                 Do you consent to us contacting you in regards to your query?
  </div>
  <div>
      <button type="Submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
      <button type="reset" name="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
    </form>
```

Can anyone help with how to use the `PHP_SELF` properly. I just want it to run the contactform.php file (which it currently does) but I want to make sure I am doing it properly.

Comment: I think your problem is with " and '. You should change the double " and use ' inside the $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"], like 'PHP_SELF'.

Comment: You can just omit the `action` attribute and just use `<form method="post">` since HTML5. Also, the `for` attribute in labels refers to an `id` attribute on the referenced input element, yours all have no `id`

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is not supposed to be used on URL.

Comment: thanks @kerbholz, I have added the id's. When I omit the action, nothing happens other than the form refreshes. How does the page know which php script to run when submit is clicked?

Comment: According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) "_When specified with no attributes, as below, the `<form>` data is sent to the same page that the form is present on_"

Comment: @Dharman That's completely incorrect.

Comment: @JP.Aulet No, that doesn't matter.  The contexts of PHP and the HTML are independent.